# Running a for loop for specific columns in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe `df` with the following observations:

```
a <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B","B", "B")
b <- c(11, 9, 4, 1, NA, 2,3,4)
c <- c(2,3, NA, NA, 25, 4, NA, 2)
d <- c(4,5, 3, NA, NA, 2,NA,NA)

df <- data.frame(a, b,c,d)
df
df <- data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- c("Letter", "num1", "num2", "num3")
df
```

Now, I would like to do my calculation with the first column with the three other columns at by using `cohen.d` function from `effsize` package, e.g: `cohen.d(df$num1, df$Letter) or cohen.d(df$num2, df$Letter`). However, before doing that, I need to remove NA values for each numerical column each calculation. The idea that pops up in my mind is I will run a `for loop` through columns `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` with `num1`. How can I use a  `for loop` for calcultions in this case?

Comment: Reshape from wide-to-long, remove NA rows, split, then use lapply.

Comment: The line `df <- data.frame(df)` does nothing, `df` already is a data.frame.

Comment: @RuiBarradas oh yes, already excluded

Comment: @zx8754 oh yeah thank you.. I did that before too, and I also did my calculations as many single steps. However, the idea is that I would like to wrap everything into one function to get the dataframe of my final results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

The following code reshapes the data, pipes to `na.omit`, then [split/lapply/combine](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v040i01) and put the results in a data.frame format.

```r
a <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B","B", "B")
b <- c(11, 9, 4, 1, NA, 2,3,4)
c <- c(2,3, NA, NA, 25, 4, NA, 2)
d <- c(4,5, 3, NA, NA, 2,NA,NA)

df <- data.frame(a, b,c,d)
colnames(df) <- c("Letter", "num1", "num2", "num3")

faux <- function(x){
  e <- effsize::cohen.d(value ~ Letter, data = x)
  e2 <- unclass(e)
  c(e2[1:4], 
    lower = unname(e2$conf.int[1]), 
    upper = unname(e2$conf.int[2]), 
    e2[6:8])
}

long <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "Letter") |> na.omit()
res <- lapply(split(long, long$variable), faux)
do.call(rbind.data.frame, res)
#>         method name   estimate        sd     lower    upper       var conf.level magnitude
#> num1 Cohen's d    d  0.9031263  3.598611 -1.155897 2.962150 0.6415931       0.95     large
#> num2 Cohen's d    d -0.7524094 10.410998 -3.754631 2.249812 0.8899453       0.95    medium
#> num3 Cohen's d    d         NA        NA        NA       NA        NA       0.95      <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit

To run the code above as a `for` loop, assign the result of `split`, explicitly create a results vector and call `faux`(auxiliary function) in the loop.

```r
sp <- split(long, long$variable)
res <- vector("list", length = length(sp))
for(i in seq_along(sp)) {
  res[[i]] <- faux(sp[[i]])
}
do.call(rbind.data.frame, res)
#>      method name   estimate        sd     lower    upper       var conf.level magnitude
#> 1 Cohen's d    d  0.9031263  3.598611 -1.155897 2.962150 0.6415931       0.95     large
#> 2 Cohen's d    d -0.7524094 10.410998 -3.754631 2.249812 0.8899453       0.95    medium
#> 3 Cohen's d    d         NA        NA        NA       NA        NA       0.95      <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It workd so well. Aber I made a mistake that I want to solve this with `for loop`. Could you produce with `for loop` becasue it is what I has been trying

Comment: @Anh Done, see the edit.

Comment: Hi @Rui Barradas Sorry for taking so long to answer you back. I also figured out end of today. But I am very happy to learn another solution here :D

Answer (score 0):

With your data, I have all NA's for cohen estimates and CI's.

However, the below is a way to have all the results at once in a `list`.

First, let's filter out NA values

```
df <- df %>% filter(!is.na(b)&!is.na(c)&!is.na(d))
```

Then, run the loop

```
mycols <- letters[2:4]
lapply(newcols, function(x) effsize::cohen.d(df[,x], df$a) )

[[1]]

Cohen's d

d estimate: NA (NA)
95 percent confidence interval:
lower upper 
   NA    NA 


[[2]]

Cohen's d

d estimate: NA (NA)
95 percent confidence interval:
lower upper 
   NA    NA 


[[3]]

Cohen's d

d estimate: NA (NA)
95 percent confidence interval:
lower upper 
   NA    NA
```

This `lapply` function is nothing else than an (implicit) loop which returns the results into a `list`.

Comment: Hi thanks @gaut, yes, that is just my fake dataset that I created. The idea is I want to remove `NA` values each column for each turn running my calculation. Btw,  your code did not run. Can you check that again?

Comment: oh sr...I did changed the column names...it worked

Comment: ah yes I forgot. edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

First, to remove the NA values you can use `tidyr::drop_na()`
this will remove any row with an NA value. Then the easiest loop is via the column names you are interested in. So just create a vector of these and use `purrr::map` to iterate over each.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Letter = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B","B", "B"),
  num1 = c(11, 9, 4, 1, NA, 2,3,4),
  num2 = c(2,3, NA, NA, 25, 4, NA, 2),
  num3 = c(4,5, 3, NA, NA, 2,NA,NA)) |>
  tidyr::drop_na() 

purrr::map(c('num1', 'num2', 'num3'),
           ~ effsize::cohen.d(df[[.x]], df$Letter))
```

Comment: drop_na would drop all the rows with NA on any column, not sure OP wants that.

Comment: @mrjoh Hi, thank you for this. Unfortunately, :( I think remove all NA values at the beginning is not what I want